# Loading external GeoJSON file into Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I would like to load a geoJSON (polygon) file into my leaflet map. I have seen examples where geoJSON is embedded into the javascript code but I can't find any examples showing how it is done with an external file.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="usStates.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 100%"</div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.3"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var map = L.map('map').setView([38.57, -94.71], 4);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/9067860284bc491e92d2342cc51d47d9/998/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'}).addTo(map);

    var featureStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5, 
        "opacity": 0.2
    };

    L.geoJson(usStates).addTo(map);

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: drag and drop the geojson onto http://geojson.io/

Comment: @Mapperz the OP was not asking about how to paste the contents of their  geojson contents into the script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

after adding `var usStates =` to the top of my geojson file the code worked.

Comment: [Wayback Machine copy of above mentioned article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160326164021/http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/osgeo-august-meeting/), as the original has succumbed to linkrot, and we can't edit others' comments.

Answer (score 53):

Look into Leaflet-Ajax.
It streamlines everything. Will give up-vote for Neogeomat for mentioning it.

Get the script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js) ([github repo](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)) and add it to your header:

```
<script src="/js/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Then it's a matter of uploading with the file name.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("foo.geojson");       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Really straight forward fix and it works. So yay.

Answer (score 32):

You can use jquery Ajax to load data and then add it.

```
var district_boundary = new L.geoJson();
district_boundary.addTo(map);

$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "data/district.geojson",
success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
        district_boundary.addData(data);
    });
}
}).error(function() {});
```

or You can use [leaflet-ajax plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)

Answer (score 21):

Here is my minimum vanilla js solution. Look ma, no jquery needed for a quick ajax call to a file.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'uk_outline.geojson');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) return
    L.geoJSON(xhr.response).addTo(map);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example -  I took out the `new` keyword for the `geoJSON` factory function, but got a CORS error with the setRequestHeader line in there, so removed it and it worked fine (must be some setting in my server).

Comment: Gives me a `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed` error at `Line Number 1, Column 1:`.  Well, since the data is a geojson, why is it trying to parse it as XML?  I don't understand the problem, but I'd like to import my data without Ajax.

Comment: @AaronBramson have another try. This was quite an old code bit which I did. I should have set the responseType and use the response not parse the responseText. Just updated the code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, this is great!  It works out of the box without requiring any extra external packages and without requiring editing the data file.  This is clearly the best answer.

Comment: How to style stroke and fill of a polygon?

Answer (score 16):

In the head element, you reference your files:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="hydro_s.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="hydro_l.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Leaflet Map with GeoJson</title>
 </head>
```

And then in the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [45.57, -73.5648],
            zoom: 10
        });

         /* Hydro */
        var hydro = new L.LayerGroup();
        L.geoJson(hydro_s, {style: hydrosStyle}).addTo(hydro);
        L.geoJson(hydro_l, {style: hydrolStyle}).addTo(hydro);

    </script>
</body>
```

You don't have to "put" them in a layer group...

Comment: perfect! this is what I was looking for!

Comment: using the Firebug web developer for firefox I am getting "ReferenceError: usStates is not defined" "(L.geoJson(usStates).addTo(map);" 
I referenced the file like you showed `<script src="usStates.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>` and added `L.geoJson(usStates).addTo(map);` to the bottom of my code. any ideas?

Comment: It must be something with src... Mine is in the head of the document (I edited my answer to add it completely)

Comment: no variable is needed for the reference? does it matter that my file extension is .json instead of .geojson?

Comment: The file can be .json or even .js. I have a variable in my example because I create a layergroup. Technically, your "L.geoJson(usStates).addTo(map);" should work. I'm not an advance Leaflet user though.

Comment: This is a confusing answer, as it requires you to define the variables hydro_s, hydro_l in your data file, which technically would make the even invalid GeoJSON! See the other answers for more info...

Comment: @fgcartographix, will the function `hydrolStyle` be similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330965/139465? The function will simply read style in the Geojson file?

Answer (score 9):

You can load external files using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with async/await alternatively:

```
async function addGeoJson() {
    const response = await fetch("filepath/filename.geojson");
    const data = await response.json();
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
}

addGeoJson();
```

Answer (score 8):

The fetch function does the job:

```
fetch("filepath/filename.geojson")
.then(function(response) {
return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
});
```