# How to add GeoJSON layer with GraphHopper?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, graphhopper

I have a GeoJSON file containing some POI that I would like to be able to display within a separate layer with GraphHopper.
But after several tries and search over internet, i can't manage to get a way to do it.

The idea is to display additional GeoJSON layers over the built-in GraphHopper ones.

Here is the code, https://graphhopper.com/#community

and what i am trying to do is to get an additional layer to display POI information from a GeoJSON file.

Here is a sample of the information available in the GeoJSON file :

```
{"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "fee": "no",
    "bicycle_parking": "anchors",
    "ref": "PVNAN23",
    "address": "Rue Gabriel Goudy 44200 Nantes",
    "name": "Pirmil P+R",
    "capacity": "24",
    "park_ride": "yes",
    "amenity": "bicycle_parking",
    "covered": "yes"
},
"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-1.5406709, 47.1960031]}},
{"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "bicycle_parking": "stands",
    "addr:postcode": "44000",
    "addr:country": "FR",
    "name": "Madeleine",
    "capacity": "6",
    "amenity": "bicycle_parking",
    "addr:street": "chaussée de la Madeleine",
    "note": "vérifié",
    "addr:city": "Nantes",
    "covered": "no",
    "addr:housenumber": "35"
},
"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-1.55076671448, 47.21000114109]}}

]}
```

The whole file has been validated in JSON validator and found no error.

I tried what is explained in this thread but nothing is working.
[How to load external GeoJSON file into Leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/how-to-load-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map)

Comment: Can you articulate what you're trying to do a bit more? I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: And can you add the code and GeoJSON you're working with?