# Load external geojson file into leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Have studied [How to load external GeoJSON file into Leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489) but not getting desired result.

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>GeoJSON data</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>
    <script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/latest/esri-leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src='https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js'></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script src='index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `index.js` looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([32.71, -85.59], 10);
var layer = L.esri.basemapLayer('Topographic').addTo(map);
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('counties.geojson', {onEachFeature:popUp}, {style:geojson});
var myStyle = {"color": "#ff7800", "weight": 4, "opacity": 0.65};
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

function popUp(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
}
```

my `index.css` looks like this:

`html, body, #map { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

A sample of the `counties.geojson` file [can be seen on `geojson.io` here](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/8c76f73be5bf610834d2/)

**How to update the files to add the `counties.geojson` data to the `ESRI basemap`?**

After that works, would like to `popUp` the `counties.geojson` properties, such as the `"NAME":` `"Cleburne"`.

**With the update to `index.css` this combo now works.**

Will need to narrow the borders on counties and change blue to an ear color, but it works. @toms refocused my attention on `index.css`.

Comment: Specifically, what is not working? `style:geojson` needs to be defined in javascript, not css. e.g. `var myStyle = {"color": "#ff7800", "weight": 5, "opacity": 0.65};`

Comment: Here [is the page](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/leaflet_0/index.html). I made your change; moved style from `.css` to `.js`. I run `firebug` but do not see any reported errors.

Comment: Doink. I forgot to add `#map` to `index.css`. It's not pretty (yet) but it's a starting point.

Comment: @toms can you tell me how to reduce the stroke on the county outlines and change the stroke color to a medium brown color (slightly darker than the ESRI map)? If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

geojson styles need to be defined in javascript, not css.

Here's a sample style:

```
var countyStyle = {
    "color": "#cec4bc", // medium? brown  
    "weight": 1,  // stroke weight in pixels
    "opacity": 0.65
};
```

You can [look up path style options here in Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path).

There are many sites to look up hex or rgb color codes and help choose colors, e.g. http://www.color-hex.com/color/ff7800