# External GeoJson file integration and showing a popup

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup

I have found a [Github](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) repository which contain sample data set to include a external geojson file and showing a popup when click on an feature.

BUt I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I have found similar questions regarding this issue in gis.stackexchange but I couldn't find a solution for my problem in those answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751488/openlayers-3-popup-with-external-geojson

[Load external geojson file into leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146408/load-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map)

This is the code I have used(Which included in github repository). I only changed the mapbox token.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
      #map{ height: 100% }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />

<script src="leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
<script src="spin.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet.spin.js"></script>




    <title>Leaflet AJAX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">var m= L.map('map').setView([42.2, -71], 8);
var osmDataAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
      var mopt = {
          url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=MY_TOKEN',
          options: {attribution:'© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'}
        };
      var osm = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",{attribution:osmDataAttr});
      var mq=L.tileLayer(mopt.url,mopt.options);

      mq.addTo(m);

      var baseMaps = {
          "Mapbox Streets": mq,
          "Open Street Map":osm
      };




function popUp(f,l){
    var out = [];
    if (f.properties){
        for(key in f.properties){
            out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
}
var jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("colleges.geojson",{onEachFeature:popUp});
var jsonpTest = L.geoJson.ajax("counties.jsonp",{onEachFeature:popUp,dataType:"jsonp"});

jsonTest.addTo(m);
var overlays={
"json":jsonTest,
"jsonp":jsonpTest
}

var lc=L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays);
lc.addTo(m);
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the index.html It shows only the basemaps (No any other map layers)

Base in the code output should be like [this](https://calvinmetcalf.github.io/leaflet-ajax/example/)

Comment: Which browser did you use to view the html file?

Comment: @ahmadhanb I used google chrome

Comment: Try to load the html in FireFox or Edge and see if the GeoJson file is loaded or not. If it is loaded then it is a chrome issue because Chrome blocks external GeoJson file and JQuery in general.  If it is not loaded then there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: I saved the geojson file as a javascript fileand assigned a variable now its working

Comment: In fact this is what I usually do to overcome calling GeoJson using JQuery.  Now I think it is better to post your solution as an answer. You can answer your own question if you don't know.

Answer (score 3):

In order to overcome this issue just save the `colleges.geojson` file as `colleges.js` and assigned the whole `colleges.js` file to a variable called colleges

```
var colleges ={"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-71.123723098996251, 42.379003083976961]}, .....
```

Now link the `colleges.js` as a javascript file to the html page

```
<script src='YOUR/PATH/TO/stations.js'></script>
```