# GeoJSON does not appear on my Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm a beginner in Leaflet and I need help to deal with GeoJSON files.

I succeeded in creating a Leaflet basemap. I can add markers without troubles but I cannot manage to show a GeoJSON layer.

Here is the code I picked up from Leaflet Tutorials website https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ :

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

Unfortunatly, the GeoJSON does not appear in my map.

Can you tell me where I missed something ?

---

Alright, you're fine Francisco, this part was OK. I changed the whole script and it works !

However, would you know how to load a GeoJSON from an external source ?

I tried this :

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("foo.geojson");       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

from [Loading external GeoJSON file into Leaflet map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/loading-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map)

but this definitely does not work.

Any ideas ?

---

I am not skilled enough to understand your advice.

Here is the whole code I am using to create my map :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>data</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
<script src="/js/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="htdocs/webmap101/leaflet.ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<style>
   #map {width: 960px; height:700px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
<script>
  // create map
var lat = 44.933331; var lon = 4.9; 
var map = L.map('map',{center: [lat,lon],zoom: 6});
  // basemaps
var base = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
 {attribution: '© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
 });
var toner = new L.StamenTileLayer("toner");
var watercolor = new L.StamenTileLayer("watercolor");
var landscape = L.tileLayer('https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
base.addTo(map);
  // markers 
var mark1=L.marker([lat,lon])
mark1.addTo(map)

  // layers panel
 L.control.layers({"base": base, "water": watercolor, "toner": toner , "landscape" : landscape}).addTo(map);

  // geojson files
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);

  //ajax 
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("foo.geojson");       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's a bit messy but this is actually my very first HTML script...
I guess I did not include in a proper way the AJAX library.

---

Actually, I just want a solution to replace the lines where I create the GeoJSON by something that tells javascript to load the GeoJSON stored locally in my folder. This :

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

should be transformed into something like (I don't know if it exists) :

```
var geojsonFeature = [foo.geosjon]
```

where "foo.geosjson" is a file like :

{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "name": "abies", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } }, "features": [ { "type": "Feature"

Comment: It seems good. Maybe the problem is in another part of the code or the html. Can you post the full code. Or there is any error in the console?

Comment: Are you running your map from server or from local file? Where is your `foo.geojson` file located?

Comment: Script is running on the localhost. My foo.geojson is in the same folder as the html.

Answer (score 4):

`L.GeoJSON.AJAX` call belongs to [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) plugin, so you should have required includes. If that part is OK and `foo.geojson` exists in your default directory and `.geojson` MIME is supported on your server, then what is missing is wait till GeoJSON data is fetched by ajax call:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("foo.geojson");
geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function(){
  geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When asking for help is a good idea open the Developer Tools of your browser ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)) and paste the output of the console, or clarify that there is no output.

Commonly is also a good idea trying to explain how you are running the code.

My bet is that you are using *Open file* in the browser and not loading the file from a (local) server. The [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) plugin that seems that you are using expects that the file *lives* in a server and can not load it from the file system.

An easy way to run a local http server, that takes as root the folder where you launch is use [reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload) if you like npm/node or [python *default server*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server)

For npm/node:

```
npx reload
# open in the browser http://localhost:8080/NAME_OF_YOUR_HTML_FILE_WITH_EXTENSION
```

For Python 3

```
python3 -m http.server
# open in the browser http://localhost:8000/NAME_OF_YOUR_HTML_FILE_WITH_EXTENSION
```

Also, to load the data in this way, it must be a valid (Geo)Json file. The data you post in your example, is defined in JavaScript, i mean, you have a variable declaration `var geojsonFeature =` and you are assigning some a literal javascript objet to it. Is just, that this "literal javascript object" is also valid geojson data. So, you `foo.geojson` file should only contain the data and not the variable declaration

**File `foo.geojson`**

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
            "name": "Coors Field",
            "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
            "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
}
```

If you want to try it in another way there is a common trick. Instead of load the data by means of an HTTP request, arrange the data to look like a JavaScript variable and load the file in a script tag. So the variable will be available in the global namespace.

As example:

**File `index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>GeoJSON tutorial - Leaflet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
        height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
       }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='map'></div>

    <script src="sample-geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
         var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);

         L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
         maxZoom: 18,
             attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                      '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                          'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
             id: 'mapbox/light-v9'
         }).addTo(map);

         L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

File **sample-geojson.js**:

```js
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

And just as final note, you don't need to use a plugin to load geojson data from the server. Is easy enough to use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or any other tool like [jQuery.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).