# Local GeoJSON in Leaflet using leaflet-ajax

Tags: qgis, leaflet, javascript, geojson, leaflet-plugins

My aim is to include a local `geojson` file in my Leaflet map application using [leaflet-ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) , as suggested by [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/102125/23204) earlier answer.

In my root directory, I have:

- `index.html`
- entire contents of [Leaflet download](https://leafletjs.com/download.html)
- `leaflet.ajax.min.js` containing the contents of the source file on [Github](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/blob/gh-pages/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js)
- `bb4326.geojson` containing 4 point features in EPSG4326

`Index.html` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hey up here!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
 
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid', {center: [52.47, -1.89], zoom: 13});

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("bb4326.geojson");       
    geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening `index.html` in a browser results in the basemap at the requested location and zoom-level, but the `geojson` file contents are not displayed. What am I overlooking? I thought that the `ajax.min.js` script ought to load the dataset for me?

`bb4326.geojson` was created by exporting a Shapefile to GeoJSON in QGIS and looks like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "bb4326",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "cat": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.903211081088789, 52.483536707820782 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "cat": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.569431757803851, 55.041100936161001 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "cat": "B" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.164490580870734, 51.446934150191545 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "cat": "C" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -3.239562634800648, 51.514642158718445 ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: do you have an error message in your browser?

Comment: See my answer at [GeoJSON does not appear on my Leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345177/geojson-does-not-appear-on-my-leaflet-map)

Comment: I've added the `geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function(){geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap)})` bit, but the layer still won't show. Perhaps leaflet-ajax isn't installed properly? Note I have just a bare html file, the leaflet download and `leaflet.ajax.min.js`.

Comment: Ar you running this from server or from file system? Any errors in the browser debugger network section?

Comment: From file system. I'm just trying this locally to see how it works. If I'm happy with the map I might rent some serverspace and register a domain.

Comment: Ok, I found an error message in the Firefox debugger: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/apps/web/bb4326.geojson. (Reason: CORS request not http)`

Comment: Referral from the error: [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp)

Comment: Problem overcome by running a local HTTP server using python, as suggested in this [earlier answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345223/23204) and also discussed in the [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server)