# Empty popups and style on a GeoJSON layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to populate popups on each polygon and style the layer according to type of commodity. Popups are empty and style doesn't work.

Code shown below:

```
lyrlicences = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/Tzlicences.geojson',{style:stylePolygons, onEachFeature:returnPolygons}).addTo(tzmap);
        
function stylePolygons(json){
    var att = json.properties;
       if(att.commoditie =='Gold'){
        return {color: 'yellow', weight:3}
       }
       
       if(att.commoditie =='Copper'){
        return {color: 'brown', weight:3}
       }
      else {
        return {color: 'red', weight:5}
       }  
}

function returnPolygons(json, layer){
  layer.bindPopup(json.properties.commoditie);
}
```

Comment: Trying to populate  popups on each polygon and style the layer according to type of commodity

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or debugger network section?

Comment: No any error message from the Console

Comment: Have a look at my answer to the question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345177/geojson-does-not-appear-on-my-leaflet-map/345227#345227.