# How to work with GeoJSON, Leaflet and pixel coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson

I'm a noob trying to piece together a - as I thought - simple thing:
A Leaflet map based on a raster picture with markers coming from a GeoJSON file. As this is a fictional map, I use the `CRS.Simple` in Leaflet and thus just use my picture pixels as coordinate system. 
From some examples I put together the following:

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -1
    });


//- set the image width and height to w and h
    var w = 1700;
    var h = 2200;

    //the stuff to be able to work with xy instead of latlon
    var yx = L.latLng;
    var xy = function(x, y) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
            return yx(x[1], x[0]);
        }
        return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
    };

    var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(w, h)];

    //this makes the map fit the bounds we just defined
    map.fitBounds(bounds).setMaxBounds(bounds);


// insert image name here
    var image = L.imageOverlay('img/background.png', bounds).addTo(map);


    //create map icon class
    var TaladasIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [50, 50],
        iconAnchor:   [25, 25],
        popupAnchor:  [0, -25]
    }
});

    //define icons
    var metropolisIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/metropolis.png'}),
        cityIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/city.png'}),
        townIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/town.png'}),
        villageIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/village.png'}),
        innIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/tankard.png'});

//- load geoJson file
    L.geoJson(json-test, {
        onEachFeature: layer.setIcon(metropolisIcon)
    }).addTo(map);
```

My GeoJSON file looks like this so far:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Cityname",
        "description": "This is a very important city",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          719,
          1210
        ]
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

There is obviously something wrong, as I only see the background image but no markers from the GeoJSON. I think it might have to do with part that exchanges latlng for xy, but honestly I'm not sure what exactly happens there. 
It does work if I define a marker directly in the script, but not from the GeojJSON. Which is a bummer because I plan on having quite a few markers and being able to write them down in a table on geojson.io would save me a lot of time.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Second try with AJAX, still not working:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  minZoom: -1
});

var w = 1700;
var h = 2200;

var yx = L.latLng;
var xy = function(x, y) {
  if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {    // When doing xy([x, y]);
    return yx(x[1], x[0]);
  }
  return yx(y, x);  // When doing xy(x, y);
};

var bounds = [xy(0, 0), xy(w, h)];
map.fitBounds(bounds).setMaxBounds(bounds);
var image = L.imageOverlay('img/kisandra.png', bounds).addTo(map);

var TaladasIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
      iconSize:     [50, 50],
      iconAnchor:   [25, 25],
      popupAnchor:  [0, -25]
  }
});

var metropolisIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/metropolis.png'}),
    cityIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/city.png'}),
    townIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/town.png'}),
    villageIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/village.png'}),
    innIcon = new TaladasIcon({iconUrl: 'img/tankard.png'});

var jsonMetropolis = new L.geoJSON();

$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "json-test.geojson",
success: function(data) {
  $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
      jsonMetropolis.addData(data);
  });
}
});

jsonMetropolis.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Any errors in the debugger console? It should be `L.geoJSON`.

Comment: good catch! I corrected the wrong cases, but the console still shows two problems: 1. syntax error on the "type" : "Feature Collection", line - the : is wrong appearantly? and 2. json is not define, which might be related

Comment: What is missing from your code above is definition of `json-test`. What is this and where does it come from?

Comment: my html file's body looks like this <div id='map'></div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/leaflet.js" ></script>
<script src="js/json-test.geojson" ></script>
<script src="js/kisandra.js"></script> where kisandra.js is what you see above. I thought putting it this way makes the html load the geoJSON first and the main script can then use it. Mistake?

Comment: If `json-test.geojson` file contains just your raw GeoJSON data, not definition of JS object in the form of `var json-test = {"type": "FeatureCollection", ...`, then it cannot work. In this case you have to first read in the GeoJSON data with AJAX (see for example leaflet-ajax plugin https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax). See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/loading-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map#

Comment: I tried the ajax plugin version as well as the jquery ajax version from that thread (for the last one I had to remove the error function from the end to make it work). With both I do not have any error messages in the console anymore. Alas, I still do not see a marker on my map...

Comment: I could try it, by I would need your `background.png` and `json-test.geojson` file.

Comment: That would be much appreciated. You ´'ll find the whole mess here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sl6ZyKmJdyYY-DxwUfHAop7VUMKEbHp2/view?usp=sharing  there are some old parts in there that I just removed by /* commenting */. Those worked but I looked for a better solution through geojson

Comment: It's getting late, so I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Of course, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer will be based on second try with AJAX (I added the code, gotten via Google drive).

There are a few things wrong in the code:

- `L.geoJSON()` is not object, but function creating an instance of object, so the correct syntax for creating GeoJSON layer is `var jsonMetropolis = L.geoJSON(...`
- When reading GeoJSON file `json-test.geojson` with AJAX, it must contain pure GeoJSON, not JS assignment in the form of `var json-test = { ...`
- Since GeoJSON data is read async, GeoJSON layer has to be added to the map when reading data is finished, inside AJAX success callback.

You can also use `pointToLayer` option to assign custom icons to GeoJSON points.

So to wrap it up, the relevant part of the code could then look something like this (tested):

```
var jsonMetropolis = L.geoJSON([], {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, yx) {
    return L.marker(yx, {
      icon: metropolisIcon
    });
  }
});

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "json-test.geojson",
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
      jsonMetropolis.addData(data);
    });
    jsonMetropolis.addTo(map);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for all your patience and work! I'm still very new to javascript and turns out it's harder than I thought. I corrected the geojson and pasted your code over what I got as import function. Unfortunately it still does not work. You can see it (or not) here: http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/test/Kisandra_map.html Must be still doing something wrong.

Comment: If you look in the browser network debugger, you'll see that browser cannot find `json-test.geojson` file on server. Either file is not there or MIME type `.geojson` is not enabled on server.

Comment: hmm... file is there: http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/test/js/json-test.geojson same directory as the js file that's calling it. Something must be wrong with just naming the file name. If I use "  url: "http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/test/js/json-test.geojson" " it works! This one I will hopefully solve on my own. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If it works when the features are defined directly in the script, it means the problem might come from the GeoJSON file. A validation with [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/) suggests to try removing the 3 trailing commas:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Cityname",
        "description": "This is a very important city"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          719,
          1210
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just tested and unfortunately that wasn't the (sole) problem.