# Loading local GeoJSON file into Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-plugins

I have an issue with loading a local GeoJSON file into a simple Leaflet map.

I followed the answer from [Loading external GeoJSON file into Leaflet map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/loading-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map):

I included the path to the leaflet.ajax.min.js as per the code below (in the head):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="plugins/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
```

And then in the script I'm adding the layer:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("CurrentPosition.geojson");       
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

When I open the index.html file, the tiles load normally, but the GeoJSON file is not there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10752055/4768502

Comment: What do you mean by local? From file system? Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section? Please edit your question with additional info